# PHP Regex to match a list of words against a string

Tags: php, regex

I have a list of words in an array. I need to look for matches on a string for any of those words.

Example word list

```
company
executive
files
resource
```

Example string

```
Executives are running the company
```

Here's the function I've written but it's not working

```
$matches = array();
$pattern = "/^(";
foreach( $word_list as $word )
{
    $pattern .= preg_quote( $word ) . '|';
}

$pattern = substr( $pattern, 0, -1 ); // removes last |
$pattern .= ")/";

$num_found = preg_match_all( $pattern, $string, $matches );

echo $num_found;
```

Output

```
0
```

Comment: What output do you expect for this example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$regex = '(' . implode('|', $words) . ')';
```

Comment: If you don't have control over the words, you should probably `array_map()` them through `preg_quote()`.

Comment: @alex But that would be TWO lines.

Comment: I think two lines is a small price to pay to make it compatible with any user inputted string :P

Comment: @alex Not if you're using Perl.

Comment: The question is tagged [php] though?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$words_list = array('company', 'executive', 'files', 'resource');
$string = 'Executives are running the company';

foreach ($words_list as &$word) $word = preg_quote($word, '/');

$num_found = preg_match_all('/('.join('|', $words_list).')/i', $string, $matches);
echo $num_found; // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the 'm' flag to make the `^` match the beginning of a line:

```
$expression = '/foo/m';
```

Or remove the `^` if you don't mean to match the beginning of a line...